# How to hide sensitive data using xslt

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0, soa

I have a requirement to modify sensitive data using xslt before entering data into database

For example -

If account number is 12345678 then it should go to database as ****5678. I have to make this changes in xslt.

As i am new to xslt i am not able to crack this.

Could you please help me out with this ??

Comment: You'd get more directed help if you provided a [mcve] of your attempt.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like:

```
<xsl:text>****</xsl:text>
<xsl:value-of select="substring(accountnumber, string-length(accountnumber) - 3)" />
```

No context was provided, so you will need to make the necessary adjustments yourself.

---

### Added:

> But what if my account number is not fixed value. For example - if account number is 123456 then it should go as **3456

I would be reluctant to provide a potential attacker information about the length of the masked portion. But if you are willing to take the risk, you can use:

```
<xsl:variable name="len" select="string-length(accountnumber)" />
<xsl:value-of select="translate(substring(accountnumber, 1, $len - 4), '0123456789', '**********')" />
<xsl:value-of select="substring(accountnumber, $len - 3)" />
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the answer. But what if my account number is not fixed value.   For example - if account number is  123456 then it should go as **3456

Comment: See that addition to my answer.